# gtk_tree_view_new How to display two icons within a new cell

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3, gtk2

[image]

I want to display the following effect, but I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the renderer as a pixbuf.

```
renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_pixbuf_new ();
```

And add an attribute for that column as "pixbuf".

```
gtk_tree_view_column_add_attribute (column, renderer, "pixbuf", colnum);
```

When setting the value in the storage, pass in a pixbuf argument.

Hope these bits of information point you in the right direction.

Comment: Dear friend, I am a novice and I don't know how to do it. Chatgpt cannot provide me with the code. Can you give me an example

Comment: The GTK3 tree-view tutorial is here: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/treeview-tutorial.html .  I recommend working through that.  I cannot supply you with code either.  You need to ask a more specific question.